# error "Unable to deduce common type for array elements." for hardcoded uint256[][]

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to define something like this?

uint256[][] A = [[1], [2], [3, 4, 5], [2, 3]];

Because right now i get this error "Unable to deduce common type for array elements."

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this, but I would like to hardcode the data

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract ArrayTest {

```
uint256[][] public test;

//i passed to _testdata [[1], [2], [3, 4, 5], [2, 3]]
function initializeAllVariants(uint256[][] memory _testdata) external {
        test = _test data;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`uint256[][] A =[ [1,3,2],[2,4,5],[3,3,3]];`

You can declare something like as long as the length of all of the sub-arrays defined in the array are the same

Comment: i do not have the same size of sub-arrays, but i have a certain number of elements.